# Initializing a structure in C gives "declaration of anonymous struct must be a definition" error

Tags: c, graph, struct

I declare a structure in my C code known as an edge

```
struct edge{
int weight;
struct node *Node1;
struct node *Node2;
};
```

where node is another structure that is defined in my code as well.
When I attempt to declare an edge in my code I use

```
struct edge *ab=(struct edge*)malloc(sizeof(struct(edge));
```

This gives me two errors: 1)declaration of anonymous struct must be a definition
2)type name requires a specifier or qualifier.

What am I doing incorrectly? For further reference my node structure is defined as

```
struct node{
char data;
struct node *parent;
} ;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
sizeof(struct(edge))
```

must be

```
sizeof(struct edge)
```

Adding `()` to a structure tag is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Update this statement

```
struct edge *ab=(struct edge*)malloc(sizeof(struct(edge));
```

the following way

```
struct edge *ab = ( struct edge* )malloc( sizeof(struct edge ) );
```

You have a redundant open parenthesis in the original statement.